# Both PNG and multi-representation TIFF in Mac App supporting retina display?

Tags: cocoa, png, tiff, retina-display

In Xcode, I add both `image.png` (normal size) and `image@2x.png` (retina size) for my images as resources.  When I build my app and look in the `/Contents/Resources/` of the bundle, it shows both an `image.png` file and an `image.tiff` file.  The TIFF contains *both* normal and retina representations.

Does `image.png` need to be included in the final app bundle?

I would think it doesn't since the TIFF file contains the same image (as well as the retina version).  It just seems to unnecessarily increase the size of the app bundle.  I'm building with the 10.8 SDK for 10.6 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned my project and rebuilt the app and the PNGs went away.  Only TIFFs are left.  I suppose I should have tried that earlier, but I'll leave this answer in case it helps anyone else.

Now you have to make sure to reference ".tiff" files in your source code though if you were referencing any PNG files.  For example:

```
// "png" changes to "tiff"
NSString *pathForImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bg" ofType:@"tiff"];
```

Comment: If you don't need to know the path of the image and just need the image itself you can use `NSImage* image = [NSImage imageNamed: @"bg"];` in which you (usually) don't need to provide the file extension. In that case you don't care if its a tiff or png.